# Java/Oracle connection performance issues

Tags: java, performance, oracle

I am using the following code to connect to an Oracle stored procedure, with an average for the `jdbcExecutionTime` of 860ms, and the execution plus serialization time of 172ms.

The `jdbcExecutionTime` concerns me, and I know it can be done much faster, but from what I've read `CallableStatement` is supposed to be the fastest.

Any hints for improving the performance here?

**Also:** I'm using `Oracle 11` with `ojdbc14.jar`.

```
final long jdbcStartTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    final long jdbcEndTime1;
    final long jdbcEndTime2;
    Connection con = null;

    logger.info("Loading properties...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

    InputStream inputStream = blah.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("properties/jdbc.properties");
    logger.info("Done loading properties...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {

        PROPERTIES.load(inputStream); //Load the jdbc properties
        Class.forName(PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")).newInstance(); //Load the oracle driver
        //Set the connection 
        logger.info("Starting JDBC connection...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.url"), PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.username"), PROPERTIES.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        ((OracleConnection)con).setDefaultRowPrefetch(80);

        logger.info("JDBC connection established...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        String jobquery =   "{call PKG_TEST.MY_PACKAGE(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";  
        CallableStatement callStmt = con.prepareCall(jobquery);

        callStmt.setString(1,blah);                     
        callStmt.setBoolean(2, blah2);
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);   
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.CURSOR);   
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(5, OracleTypes.CURSOR);   
        callStmt.registerOutParameter(6, OracleTypes.CURSOR);   

        jdbcEndTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        logger.info("Executing stored procedure...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        callStmt.execute();
        logger.info("Stored procedure complete...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        logger.info("Storing db cursor objects as result sets...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());
        ResultSet cur1 = (ResultSet)callStmt.getObject(3);
        ResultSet cur2 = (ResultSet)callStmt.getObject(4);
        ResultSet cur3 = (ResultSet)callStmt.getObject(5);
        ResultSet cur4 = (ResultSet)callStmt.getObject(6);
        logger.info("Completed storing cursors...SYS TIME:"+System.currentTimeMillis());

        jdbcEndTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        final long jdbcExecutionTime =  (jdbcEndTime1-jdbcStartTime1);
        final long spEx_ResultSetTime = (jdbcEndTime2-jdbcEndTime1);
```

Comment: OK, so it takes 860ms to open the connection and set up the `CallableStatement`.  How much of that time is spent opening the connection and how much is spent setting up the `CallableStatement`?  Are you opening a new physical connection?  Assuming that the vast majority of the time is spent opening the connection, is that really something you care to optimize?  When you deploy this code, are you really going to be opening a new physical connection for every procedure that you execute rather than grabbing a connection from a connection pool?

Comment: You should consider updating your old driver.

Comment: @Michael-O what's wrong with my driver?

Comment: The Java 1.4 is really old. There have been a lot of fixes since then. It's best to try the most recent one to avoid driver related issues.

Comment: @Michael-O But I believe that jar covers up to Java 5, do you think that would really effect the performance?

Comment: I can't tell but a test is trivial. It's worth trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you do this, most of the time will be spent loading the library (which only happens when you use it for the first time) and creating the connection.  Once you have an existing connection you should expect around a <10 ms delay (longer than what you are doing)